# Upload image to FTP

Tags: php, image, ftp

From my Swift application I´m sending an image file to my PHP script and from my PHP script I want to upload it to my FTP.

Here is my script

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "My FTP";
$ftp_user = "Username";
$ftp_pass = "Password";
$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$remote_file = "test.png"; 

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}

// upload a file 
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) { 
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n"; 
    exit; 
} 
else { 
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n"; 
    exit; 
} 

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);  
?>
```

I´m connecting to the server and I´m able to upload a file BUT my issue is that the file I´m uploading is corrupt. I think it has to do with my `$remote_file = "test.png";`. Is it the right way to use `ftp_put`to upload the file and does anyone has a clue why it´s corrupt?

Comment: You want to use the 70th `ftp` protocol? Seriously? In 2016?

Comment: @arkascha, I don´t have a lot of experience of PHP. Maybe you could provide an updated example?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a php issue, it is a general question of networking. The old `ftp` protocol dates back to an era long gone. It has several issues which suggest that you want to use a modern replacement like `sftp` or `webdavs` instead... `ftp` offers no encryption, so everyone in the internet can read your password and data and it is a nightmare for network administrators because of its inflationary use of ports for file exchange...

Comment: I can take a look at `sftp`but for now I have an issue with the corrupt file and that´s an PHP issue @arkascha

Comment: Is the file really an ASCII formatted file, or is it rather a binary one?

Comment: @user5855868 What you you *really* need to do, is sniff out what type of file is being uploaded http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php & use a conditional statement based on what's being uploaded where you could use both methods, ascii or binary. You're using `FTP_ASCII` to upload a binary file and that will fail somewhat. Oh, it'll work alright, but you'll be seeing a whole bunch of weird characters, rather than the file itself, being an image, not strings. My comment here "answers" the question, where the answer you accepted did not and is considered as a low-quality answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "My FTP";
$ftp_user = "Username";
$ftp_pass = "Password";
$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$remote_file = "test.png"; 

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}

// upload a file 
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) { 
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n"; 
    exit; 
} 
else { 
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n"; 
    exit; 
} 

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);  
?>
```

Comment: That did it!! Thanks :)

Comment: Any ideas how to change the code above to the `sftp`protocol?

Comment: So finally you have the file where you want it to ;-)

Comment: Look at **ftp_ssl_connect()** (requires openSSL installed) and the series of functions beginning with **ssh2_sftp_&hellip;** on the _php.net_ website.

Comment: This is a low-quality answer where no explanation was given. I had to sift through it myself and compare it with the OP's code to see what you changed. Future visitors to the question and less-experienced coders will scratch their head for a while to see what the problem really was.